# C++ -- Join a vector of threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am using g++ 4.8 to write a c++11 program. I'm trying to convert a single threaded program to multi-threaded one. The join in the threaded version ends up throwing a compilation error. Could you please let me know where I'm going wrong?

Single Threaded(works well):
Note that all arguments are pass by reference.

```
for (const auto& i : vec_clients)
{
    i->startSim(vec_masters, vec_trace1, vec_trace2, vec_trace3);
}
```

Multi-Threaded version:

```
std::vector<std::thread> vec_thr;
for (const auto& i : vec_clients)
{
    std::thread t1(&Client::startSim, std::move(i), std::move(vec_trace1), std::move(vec_trace2), std::move(vec_trace3));
    vec_thr.push_back(std::move(t1));
}
for (unsigned int i=0; i<vec_thr.size(); ++i)
{
    // if (i.joinable())
        vec_thr.at(i).join();
}
```

Modified(simpler example):

```
class Test
{
private:
public:
    void testme(const std::string& _str)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello "+_str << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(const int argc, const char **argv)
{
    std::string str = "there";
    Test t1;
    std::vector<std::thread> vec_thr;
std::thread thr1(&Test::testme, std::move(t1), std::cref(str));
    vec_thr.push_back(thr1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "ends up throwing an error"? Do you get a build error? A crash? An exception? Something else? Please elaborate.

Comment: *"an error"* just cost you 2 downvotes.

Comment: Also note that you can still pass arguments by reference even using `std::thread`. Use [`std::ref` or `std::cref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) like e.g. `std::thread t1(&Client::startSim, i, std::cref(vec_trace1), std::cref(vec_trace2), std::cref(vec_trace3))`

Comment: _@AJES123_ Post a [MCVE] please.

Comment: Lastly you should know that [`std::thread::joinable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable) doesn't tell you if the thread has finished or not, just if you could call [`join`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) on the thread. The [`join`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) call may still block.

Comment: Wow, multiple belts and suspenders! The threads have not been detached, so there is no need to test whether they are joinable. And the loop goes from `0` to `vec_thr.size()`, so there's no need to test whether the loop index is in range.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ  : Added a minimal code for your reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is still interested, this is the answer:

```
class Test
{
private:
public:
    void testme(const std::string& _str)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello "+_str << std::endl;
    }

    void testme2(const std::string& _str)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello to "+_str << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(const int argc, const char **argv)
{
    std::string str = "there";
    std::unique_ptr<Test> up1(new Test());
    std::unique_ptr<Test> up2(new Test());
    std::vector<std::thread> vec_thr;
    std::thread thr1(&Test::testme, std::move(up1), std::ref(str));
    std::thread thr2(&Test::testme2, std::move(up2), std::ref(str));
    vec_thr.push_back(std::move(thr1));
    vec_thr.push_back(std::move(thr2));
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<vec_thr.size(); ++i)
    {
        vec_thr.at(i).join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Integer `i` does not have a `joinable` member function (or any member function as it is a primitive type). It should be:

```
for (unsigned int i=0; i<vec_thr.size(); ++i)
{
    if (vec_thr[i].joinable())
        vec_thr.at(i).join();
}
```

Or just use `join` on the thread. I see no particular reason to do `joinable` test here as you are not `detaching` any of the threads.

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo. I had commented the joinable part...not sure when it got deleted...    
        //~ if (i.joinable())

Comment: Ok, So, if this wasn't the issue, can you update the question and also post the error message that you are getting in that case ?

Comment: /usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:135:25: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = Client; _Dp = std::default_delete<Client>]’
       : _M_head_impl(__h) { }
                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:81:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:40,
                 from src/DataEngine.h:31,
                 from src/DataEngine.cpp:24:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:273:7: error: declared here
       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
       ^